# add second field when uipickerview in countdowntimer mode in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker

i have a  functionility for show count down timer in format, but when uidatepicker in count down timer mode , it show only HH:MM.

```
how i can add a extra field for second in uidatepickerview.
```

Answer (score 3):

> how i can add a extra field for second in uidatepickerview.

You can't.  `UIDatePicker` only displays hours and minutes in countdown mode.  If you need to display seconds as well, you'll have to recreate it yourself using a `UIPickerView`.

As always, you should file an [enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com) to request this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{
return 2;
}
```

it will create section in your picker view.